# Extract the text of particular tag within string

Tags: jquery, html, find

I have some text in p tag. I would like to extract the first `img` tag text.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <img width ="50" src ="djdjdj.jpg"></img>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <img width ="50" src ="sfdsfdsfdsf.jpg"></img>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

So what I would like as a result is :

```
<img width ="50" src ="djdjdj.jpg"></img>
```

I tried

```
 $("p").find("img").text()
```

But it's not working.

Comment: if you want to get the `img` element within the `p` tag, then just remove the `.text()` in your call.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on Chrome, and it works:

```js
console.log($("p img:first")[0].valueOf());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <img width="50" src="djdjdj.jpg"></img>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <img width="50" src="sfdsfdsfdsf.jpg"></img>quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
  anim id est laborum.</p>
```